# Вызов функции с передачей параметра в условном операторе

Tags: bash

В директории имеется исполняемый файл a.out
Я вызываю его в if, передав параметр, записанный в переменную, ожидая реакции в зависимости от выходного значения.

```
    if $(./a.out < $TMP)
    then
        ...
```

На что интерпретатор выдает ошибку об отсутствии файла.
Прошу помочь с этим вопросом: как в условном операторе проверять результат своих команд, при этом передавая им изменяющиеся параметры? Спасибо

Comment: Без передачи параметра (< $TMP) всё работает нормально. Поэтому вопрос можно перефразировать: как передавать параметры в свои команды, чтобы bash это правильно понимал?

Comment: ну, bash-скрипт это же просто последовательность команд описанных там. Вы же не выполняете свой скрипт вот так `./a.out < $TMP` ? Вы наверно делаете это как-то так `./a.out arg1 arg100500 "multi args as one string"` , смекаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Если параметров больше чем 1
TMP=( 'param_1' 'param_2' ... 'param_N' )    
# Если параметр один
TMP='param'

if $(./a.out "${TMP[@]}")
        then
            ...
```

Comment: Понял, в чем была моя ошибка. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

оператор `<` в конструкции вида:

```
команда < файл
```

означает перенаправление ввода:

будет открыт для чтения указанный файл, и получен дескриптор, а затем этот дескриптор будет связан с *stdin* (стандартным потоком ввода) процесса, запущенного в результате интерпретации указанной команды.

указанного вами файла, судя по всему, не существует, о чём вы и получаете сообщение от интерпретатора.

---

судя по упомянутому вами слову «параметр», вы хотели передать имя файла как параметр вызываемой программе. значит так и надо было написать, без оператора перенаправления:

```
программа файл
```

Comment: Ошибся в терминах, спасибо. С перенаправлением ввода не получалось, зато получилось с параметром, как посоветовал человек выше.